# Ionic 5 passing params and header on http

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am now trying to connect the Odoo with Ionic 5 app. I did api on Odoo side and can call using Postman.

[image]

[image]

below is my code but not success

```
     baseUrl:string = "https://myappjob.com";

  constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

  public authenOdoo(){
    let headers_ = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    this.http
    .get(this.baseUrl + '/authen', "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"params\":{\"login\":\"myname@myappjob.com\", \"pwd\":\"mypasswordhere\"}}", headers_)
    .then(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("ERROR!: ", JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    );

  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8yij.png)

how can I call using HTTPClient or HTTP?

Best Rgds,
joozer

Comment: Stop Uploading Images and Share your Code.

Comment: updated with code.

Comment: What Error are you receiving?

Comment: If you're using HTTP module of angular then you should subscribe to it instead of attaching then block.